# Is there a NetworkX algorithm to find the longest path from a source to a target?

Tags: python, networkx

I need to find a longest path in an **unweighted** graph from *s* to *t*.

I am using NetworkX, which has an algorithm for finding a longest path in a directed, acyclic graph, but I am not able to specify the source and the target nodes.

I have not been able to find any info online, but it seems like such an obvious algorithm to have laying around. Is there any way I can do this?

Comment: Could you not simply inverse the weights of the edges and then look for the shortest path with one of the build in solutions within networkx?

Comment: I suppose this could work, my network being unweighted, all edges would simply have -1 as weight

Comment: The only thing is that the dijsktra would end up failing on instances with cycles

Comment: There is no efficient algorithm to do this. (It's NP hard).  Here's a song about it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a3ww0gwEszo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"[T]he longest path problem is the problem of finding a simple path of maximum length in a given graph."<sup>[[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_path_problem)]</sup>

NetworkX has a [`simple_paths`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/simple_paths.html) module, that contains the function [all_simple_paths](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.simple_paths.all_simple_paths.html#networkx.algorithms.simple_paths.all_simple_paths).

Below is one solution for finding the longest simple paths between two nodes.

```python
from typing import List
import networkx as nx 

def longest_simple_paths(graph, source, target) -> List[List]:
    longest_paths = []
    longest_path_length = 0
    for path in nx.all_simple_paths(G, source=source, target=target):
        if len(path) > longest_path_length:
            longest_path_length = len(path)
            longest_paths.clear()
            longest_paths.append(path)
        elif len(path) == longest_path_length:
            longest_paths.append(path)
    return longest_paths


G = nx.complete_graph(4)
longest_paths = longest_simple_paths(G, source=0, target=3)
if longest_paths:
    print(f"Longest simple path contains {len(longest_paths[0])} nodes")
    print(longest_paths)
```

#### Output

```
Longest simple path contains 4 nodes
[[0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 2, 1, 3]]
```

---

<sup>[1]</sup> Wikipedia contributors. "Longest path problem." Wikipedia, The Free Encyclopedia. Available from: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_path_problem. Accessed 8 November 2020.

Comment: Should highlight that there is no known efficient algorithm to find the longest path in a large network (and it is very unlikely that a quick algorithm exists).

Comment: There is however places online where it is possible to find people claiming that they can do it it pseudopolynomial time